# Set initial viewController in Navigation controller programmatically (Layer SDK)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add [Layer SDK](https://github.com/kwkhaw/Layer-Parse-iOS-Swift-Example) to my application (using Swift).

All view controllers here are created programmatically. Therefore I can't segue to them. I have 4 tabs in my application (`UITabBarController`). One of them is chat. In the chat tab I created a segue to `UINavigationController`. Now I want to load `conversationListViewController` in this `UINavigationController`. For that I created a class for this UINavigationController i.e. `ConversationListViewController` and added the following code:

```
class ChatNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {
  var conversationListViewController: ConversationListViewController!
    var layerClient: LYRClient!
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!AppDelegate
        self.layerClient = appDelegate.layerClient
        self.conversationListViewController = ConversationListViewController(layerClient: appDelegate.layerClient)
        self.conversationListViewController.displaysAvatarItem = true

        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.conversationListViewController, animated: true)
      }
}
```

But this is not working. And giving this kind of effect: the `ConversationViewController` is not loaded in `UINavigationController`. I am not sure if I am doing it the correct way. I'm searching for the correct way, but unable to find.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it's easy , create  your view controller in storyBoard and embed it on UINavigationController , set the identfire for your navigation controller, then : set your root view controller as [[YourNavigationController viewControllers]firstObject]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Solved it. I dragged new `NavigationViewController` and added `ConversationListViewController` to rootviewController.I think i should try this first. Anyways thanks guys for your help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to do this programatically:

You need to manually initialize the controller before stacking it up on the Navigation Controller. Try this:

navigationController?.pushViewController(self.conversationListViewController.**init()**, animated: true)

Comment: var tempVC = ChatFriendsVC()
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(tempVC.dynamicType.init(), animated: true)  . Tried this but not getting the output.

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let vc = self.conversationListViewController.init()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

Comment: But this is not extending  `TableViewController`.

Comment: What is the controller that you have put in the snapshot? Shouldn't that be a `TableViewController` ?

Comment: This are the extra menus in my `TabBarController` :)

Comment: A `TabBarController` should load a `TableViewController` which initializes and loads the `ViewController`.   From the information provided in the question, it is difficult to suggest beyond this.